# Mass Update a property on multiple records inside a dictionary (VB.NET / C#)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, dictionary

I have a Dictionary (of Long, Class), where Class has multiple properties (assume we have a property called Updated as Boolean).

I want to update this (Updated) property to (True) at once for let's say all Odd key records (or based on any specific rule). What is the best way to do so?

My thoughts are to use Linq to fetch those records then (for each) them, but is there any better way to do so like doing a mass update where a condition happens (like what we do in the database)?

An example of my approach is below. Appreciate it if there is a better way to do such an update...

Thanks

```
Dim ReturnedObjs = From Obj In Dictionary Where Obj.Key Mod 2 = 1
For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of Long, Class) In ReturnedObjs
    item.Value.Updated = True
Next
```

Comment: This sounds like a case for the Speed Rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: So what's wrong with your current approach? What are you trying to fix?

Comment: If you have data coming each 100ms, and you want to update 10k records (or even more), this will be useful :) I'm trying to optimize this in the best possible way. If there is a way to simply update all records directly this will be great (like when we say in SQL 'Update Table Set Property = True where Value > 0' for example)

Comment: You could write the equivalent of a `For Each` loop for Linq, but even then, you're only hiding the iteration.  I don't see the point; quite a lot of Linq is useful for query comprehensions or deferred execution, this would serve neither purpose.  You're going to need to iterate, might as well make it explicit (especially if you need to update more than one property of the enumeration variable).

Answer (score 2):

First, this sounds like a obvious case for the speed rant:

https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Second:

The best way is to keep this in the Database. You are not going to beat the speed of a DB Query with Indexes designed for quick matching, by transfering the data over the network twice (once to get it, once to return it) and doubling the search load (once to get all odd ones, once to update all the ones you just changed). My standing advice is to always keep as much work as possible on the DB side. Your client code will never be able to beat it.

Third:

**If** you do need to use client side processing:

Now a lot of my answer depend on details of the implementation, how the JiT and general Compiler optimsiations work, etc.

Foreach uses works on enumerators, not Collections. But if you feed a collection to foreaach, a Enumerator is implicitly created. Now enumerators do have two properties:

1. If the collection changes, the Enumerator becomes invalid. Most people learn about them because they ran into this issue.
2. It is a extra function call and set of checks for accessing a collection. So it will be a slowdown. How much is hard to say, as the Optimisations and JiT are pretty good.

So you propably want to use for loop instead.

If you could turn the Dictionary into a collection where the Primary Key is used as Index, it might be a bit faster. But hat has the danger of running into a lot of "dry spells" regarding data, so it depends a lot on your source data.

Comment: Well, I don't see this as a "speed rant" of such. I knew a way to implement this (which I put above which might help someone), and I'm searching for something better if exists (learning something new is always good). If there is a better way to do something, then why not doing it the right way? Even if it is running ok. Let's say am a perfectionist and like to do things the best way possible :)

Comment: Now for the rest of your answer ;) The second point, unfortunately doing this on DB is not an option... The data actually is coming from the front-end. and sending this to the server to be processed in the database (for many users) will be consuming server resources. That's why it is better to distribute the processing for each front-end using the updating from the LINQ statement as described in my post. And we don't need this on the DB anyways (it is completely front-end visual thing to users).

Comment: For the third suggestion, I will check the 'For Loop', thanks for the detailed explanation for the 'For Each'. I was hoping that there would be a way to do such a mass update without iteration :)

Comment: @AhmadMusa I hope with all those layers of seperation, you accounted for Race Conditions? Particular the Update Race Condition can lead to lost update and this sounds like a ideal breeding ground for them.

Comment: @christopher this is not related to a race condition scenario. As mentioned I was just looking if there is a better way to do such an update that I do not know. The code is working and am not complaining. But for huge amount of records the cpu will start increasing (obviously). So I wondered if we are missing a different technique (searched several sites without finding anything, hence my question here). Thanks :)